# jQuery deferred method and ajax beforeSend()

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

By using the deferred object in $.ajax

- the success-callback can replaced by the `deferred-method done()`
- the error-callback acn replaced by the `deferred-method fail()`
- and the complete-callback can by replaced by `always()`

by using

```
var jqxhr = $.ajax({
                url: Config.baseUrl+"/ajax/favourites/set-favourite.ajax",
                dataType: "json",
                data: attrs,
                type: "POST",
                beforeSend: function(){
                    console.log("before send");
                }
            });
```

how can i implement the `beforeSend-callback` by using the deferred object?

why i don't use the beforeSend-callback inside the `$.ajax` function?
Because the request is inside a Model-Instance (http://canjs.com/docs/can.Model.model.html#section_Non_standardServices)
so the model object do the request and all the other suff, like manipulate the DOM will done in the deferred object.
i would like to manipulate the DOM before sending the ajax request.

how could i do that?

Comment: I don't think you can (unless it is a `progress`, but I guess it would be fired before the returned promise is constructed). Why do you need a callback for this?

Comment: as i wrote... i would like to manipulate the DOM before sending the ajax request.

Comment: The request has already been made when you add deferred methods to the returned promise, so you can't add one afterwards that needs to be executed beforehand. Maybe you can tie into a default beforeSend (using $.ajaxSetup)?

Comment: @JuKe: But what does hinder you manipulating the DOM simply before invoking the ajax method (or right after starting the request)? Why would you need a beforeSend callback?

Comment: @Bergi consistency. It's annonying that they covered **nearly** every case;

Answer (score -1):

You could attach the global jQuery event `ajaxStart` to whatever element is triggering your AJAX request. That should essentially replicate the functionality of `beforeSend`.

```
$(".ajax").ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".document").append("AJAX begun");
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63uznra4/).